# How to call a function from imported class?

Tags: react-native

I want to call a function from an imported class. This is my code

```
import test from '../test'
test.showMessage();  // This is not working
```

this is the content of the test component

```
export default class test {
showMessage(){
alert('Some text');
}
}
```

I get an error telling me that showMessage is not a function. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `showMessage()` static :

```
export default class test {
  static showMessage(){
    alert('Some text');
  }
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the method static like @Himanshu suggested, or you can initiate an instance of your class:

```
import test from '../test'
const myTest = new test()

myTest.showMessage();  // This works
```